# Android, An impossible Memory Leak, How to find it with eclipse?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks

I am metting an OutOfMemory exception after a while, while inflating an XML View with a bitmap.

The problem occurs after opening many times activities that are using many bitmap but always inflated from the XML.

I check with MAT the Memory. 
First question : I don't retain any of my Activity in memory
- If I filter on the name of my Activity, i get Objects = 0, but on some activities 
I could see RetainedHeap >= 302. Does this indicate a leak ?

After that, I try to compare my memory in different point of time, to see the objects that have been created. But I can't find any thing significant.

My Question is : If I don't retain activities in memory what could be the leak reason ?
What tools/Method to use to find it ?

Regards,

Olivier

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all references to the bitmaps to `null` when the Activity is destroyed.  This may not answer your questions but it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have big source images then scale them to target size: [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue/3549021#3549021)
2. Cache Bitmaps (but not Drawables!!) in a List (or Map) and save them in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am caching drawable but I clear the callback reference when I destroy my Activity. I think it's better to cache drawable, because otherwise each time you set a bitmap to an imageView you create indirectly an new drawable. My problem is more, I have got a leak on bitmaps, but I don't retain any activity in memory, but How can I find this leak ?